# What should my family do to notify SE if I die?

Tags: discussion

I'm updating various morbid documents and have come to wonder whether there is any established protocol for "memorialising" accounts in the way that some social media networks do?

I'm not asking for some wonderful shrine to be put up on my profile, and at its most basic my will could just ignore Stack Overflow/Exchange completely, letting my account fade into oblivion without anyone out here knowing why. But, if the SE team has a system by which family members can *report* a dead contributor for whatever reason (even if just to permanently lock-out account access), I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: I am saddened and disappointed that it sound s like the shrine I’ve been building all these years may never be put to good use.  :P

Comment: @animuson: That's the badger, ta

Comment: Light in a vacuum does not die, it just averages out.

Comment: @Won't: Well that's a comfort :P

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could leave your login details in some sealed file that your family would be able to access after your death. Then they can at least put a note on your profile. (This is assuming that you trust them not to run riot and use your account to rampage across SE until it gets suspended ;-) )

This is what was done with the user [Affable Geek](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/1039/affable-geek), whose profile says, in a bold note at the top:

> Michael went to be with the Lord on February 14, 2015. He considered this his favorite hangout. I know he would have wanted to leave you an explanation for his lack of activity on this site.

He was also remembered in [meta posts](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4496/lets-take-a-moment-to-remember-affable-geek) on his main and even [other](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7204/31394) SE sites. But that was all due to users who wished to commemorate him, nothing to do with the SE team.

Comment: _"in some sealed file that your family would be able to access "_ aka _"The Grail"_ :-P ...

Comment: The sealed file is exactly what I'm putting together. My question is ... what should the instructions it contains say! Ofc if there's no formal process then this'll suffice, thanks